# PHP string comparison of same word problem

Tags: php, string, comparison

I am opening some files with fopen and in these files i read a word and put it in a variable. The word is "hour" . But later when i compare this variable with the word "hour" it doesnt return equal ! The problem may have something to do with the encoding. Is there any way to format the encoding so it matches with the common text?

Here is a sample of the code refering to the problem i am facing:

```
$myfile = fopen("/hdd4/no2_2013_2016/".$files[$i], "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$raw_text=fgets($myfile)
$text_array=explode(",",$raw_text);
$frequency=$text_array[10];  // It is hour and it reads it correctly as i echoed it
echo strcmp($frequency, "hour"); // not 0 ,in fact it returns -104 .Also the number my differ with other files

if ($frequency=="hour") //also doesn't work
```

As suggested I used `var_dump($frequency)` and it returned:

```
string(9) "\000h\000o\000u\000r\000"
```

After `trim($frequency)` it returned:

```
string(7) "h\000o\000u\000r"
```

Comment: `var_dump($frequency);` you'll probably need `trim`.

Comment: var_dump returned  string(9) "\000h\000o\000u\000r\000"

Comment: You might want to see how you're saving it in the file, because it's not saving as "hour"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a *null character* before each character.  If you are creating the file then you are not doing it properly.  Presumably something is putting one character at a time to the file and each put is terminated by a *null character*, or that happened in a previous step.

If it is outside of your control then replace that character:

```
$raw_text = str_replace("\0", "", fgets($myfile));
```

Comment: That fixed the problem thank you so much for your time!